# What tense to use writing about laws?

Tags: prepositions, tense, past-tense, legalese

If the law was adopted some time ago and is still effective, what tense and preposition to use?

> The law IS effective ON July 1, 2014.

vs

> The law IS effective SINCE July 1, 2014.

vs

> The law HAS BEEN effective SINCE July 1, 2014.

Comment: What would be *your thoughts* and why? We are happy to help, but this type of question is usually frowned upon. See more here: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please/443#443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More common, I think, is...

> The law **[is in effect](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=RSd3GXebBfcC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=%22law%20is%20in%20effect%20since%22&source=bl&ots=guhzUmrlv2&sig=ea0USnfp87qQvqahZe4KEWRM1uQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VtG4VIHiDNGMuASa0YHYCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22law%20is%20in%20effect%20since%22&f=false)** since July 1, 2014 **OR** 
>  The law **[has been in effect](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#tbm=nws&q=%22law%20has%20been%20in%20effect%20since%22)** since July 1, 2014.

In such cases, when you use *is/has been* it talks about the period of time.

---

*Just to play a pun*

Law is *in effect* talks about the power it imposes, on the other hand 'law is effective' makes it non-mandatory! The law is effective, but if you don't practice it, it's up to you!